# Railguns in Space: Muzzle Velocity

Tags: electromagnetism, velocity, projectile, space

I've done some searching around the internet for some theoretical information on Railguns being used in space, but I only seem to be getting results about Earth-based Railguns being used to fire equipment, etc. into space. Hopefully the good people of this site may be able to help a layman understand a few things about Railguns that are, themselves, in space.

I would like to pose a hypothetical scenario to work from.
Say that, in space, we have a Railgun comparable to today's prototypes (a more specific example would be General Atomics's Blitzer weapon). For this example, it has a muzzle energy of 64 megajoules and muzzle velocity of approximately 9000 km/s. For the sake of this example, we have an adequate supply of energy produced by the weapons platform.

From what I understand, the Muzzle Velocity is the **initial** velocity at which the projectile travels from out of the barrel of the weapon. Then, it begins to be affected by the friction in the air, gradually slowing it down from near-orbital re-entry speeds.

Suppose, then, that this weapon is in space, where there is no air and therefore **virtually no drag**.

Does this mean that the projectile will continue seemingly forever, at around the same Muzzle Velocity, until it comes into contact with something?

Thank you

Comment: I was just thinking about this very topic so I did a search. One thing that does come to mind is that inertia would cause the gun and the projectile to travel in opposite directions. So you would want a fairly heavy gun and light projectile. Then you have to consider g-forces, so probably no humans on board. Probably would take a fair bit of energy as well. Then, what happens at the presumed destination to stop the projectile?

Answer (score 0):

The projectile's velocity is only affected by a net force. Just because there's no drag does not mean there is no net force. The matter in space (planets, stars, etc) will exert gravitational forces which will alter the projectile's velocity and trajectory. However, if you assume there are no other bodies, your projectile will still probably change velocity (though very slowly) due to ejection of individual molecules and radiation of energy.

Comment: Ah, well yes of course, I figured it may continue going provided nothing interferes with its trajectory, which is easier to say in Space than in our planet's atmosphere.

I suppose this means that a Railgun projectile will reliably continue at practically the same speed as its Muzzle Velocity for several thousand kilometers, which by then it would be out of meaningful range for the user.